# Oracle: Recover source code/table structures from "utterly wiped out" development database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, disaster-recovery

Given an Oracle 11.1 database used for development, running in NOARCHIVELOG mode, where all datafiles (including undo) have been wiped out; and only SYSTEM and SYSAUX datafiles and control file remain (and even then, just as hot backup of disk taken while database was open; not as database/RMAN backup), is there any way to open a "skeletal" version of the database such that source code and table schemas can be retrieved?  No concerns whatsoever for data recovery/integrity/etc; just want to retrieve whatever data dictionary contents that are possible (given these scraps of the original).

Comment: Don't have an instance running, but these should get you started. https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c05dicti.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datadict.htm#CNCPT2140. You should be able to probe around and at least find your column definitions &c. in there somewhere. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

In order to start the instance without interfering with an existing running instance (e.g ORCL), before starting anything:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create pfile='/tmp/initORCL2.ora' from spfile='?/dbs/spfileORCL.ora';
exit
```

Edit `/tmp/initORCL2.ora`, and modify (add if doesn't exist) the `instance_name`:

```
*.instance_name='ORCL2'
```

Prevent listener registration, e.g:

```
*.local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=DUMMY)))'
```

Create the new spfile:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create spfile='?/dbs/spfileORCL2.ora' from pfile='/tmp/initORCL2.ora';
exit
```

And continue according to the original steps:

```
export ORACLE_SID=ORCL2
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

*If you don't use spfile, simply copy and edit the initORCL.ora.*

**/UPDATE**

```
startup nomount
```

You have lost the UNDO tablespace, so switch to manual undo management:

```
alter system set undo_management=manual scope=spfile sid='*';
```

You have lost the redo logs and your remaining datafiles are in an inconsistent state, so you will not be able to open the instance, unless you allow resetlogs corruption:

```
alter system set "_allow_resetlogs_corruption"=true scope=spfile sid='*';
```

Mount the database:

```
startup force mount
```

You have lost the datafiles, so you will not be able to open the instance, unless you offline drop the datafiles:

`select name from v$datafile;`

```
alter database datafile '/database/users01.dbf' offline drop;
alter database datafile '/database/undotbs01.dbf' offline drop;
...
```

In order to perform open resetlogs, and incomplete media recovery should be performed (even if it can not do anyhting):

```
recover database until cancel;
```

At this point you *should be* able to open the instance:

```
alter database open resetlogs;
```

*Should be*, because depending on the scale of inconsistency of the remaining SYSTEM datafile, the  instance may not open at all, or it may crash immediately or in best case scenario, it may open and remain stable so you can query `DBA_SOURCE`, `SYS.SOURCE$`, etc.

Comment: Fantastic response!  May be later this week, but I'll give this a whirl and let you know how it works out.

Comment: [ETA] One question - how would I (or can I) integrate into this approach the need to open this database with a different SID/global name than that with which it crashed?  Project team is already at work on new version of dev db under original database name (with all indications that recovery of a couple packages would still be of great help).  Last thing I want to do is disrupt that further with this recovery effort.  Don't really have alt. env. to attempt recovery on though.

Comment: Updated my answer for this.

Comment: Tried to startup twice, got ORA-00600 both times.  SCN incremented slightly between.  First attempt: ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [2662], [3293], [1796330011], [3293], [1798905637], [4194398], [], []
Second attempt:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [2662], [3293], [1796330015], [3293], [1798905637], [4194398], [], []

Comment: [eta] should probably mention following SQL> recover database until cancel;
ORA-00279: change 14145123635743 generated at 05/28/2015 11:57:25 needed for thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /[trimmed]/2015_05_28/o1_mf_1_1_%u_.arc
ORA-00280: change 14145123635743 for thread 1 is in sequence #1

Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
CANCEL
ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '[trimmed]system01.dbf'
ORA-01112: media recovery not started